# Django Serializer Method Field with 2 or more fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to extend my serializer from existing table.

```
class SER_Assets(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    asset_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_asset_id(self, obj):
       t1 = Tbl.objects.get(tbl_id=obj.id)
       return t1.asset_id

    def get_asset_name(self, obj):
       ..
```

i know this method.. both function going to call same table i want to reduce function. so i need to call single function to return multiple fields.

is that possible?

Comment: Can you edit your question and clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish? I don't understand.

Comment: If `asset_id` and `asset_name` are model fields you don't have to fetch it manually. you just have to mention those column name in fields attribute of class Meta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call method once to set multiple fields in Django Rest Framework serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663579/call-method-once-to-set-multiple-fields-in-django-rest-framework-serializer)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [`serializers.ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer), if the field is a model field then you can just mention the name of the model field.

**Note:** You can use [`serializers.SerializedMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) if you need to do some manipulation on a field.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ["asset_id", "asset_name", "field_3"]
        # You can also use __all__ if you want to include all the fields
        # fields = "__all__"
```

`ModelSerializer` behaves very similar to Django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `.save()` ModelSerializer's method, you can pass `**kwargs` into it. By this, you can save multiple dynamic values.

i.e. `.save(**{'foo':'bar', 'lorem':'ipsum'})`

Answer (score -2):

```
class SER_Assets(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_compound = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_asset_compound(self, obj):
        t1 = Tbl.objects.get(tbl_id=obj.id)
        return {"asset_id": t1.asset_id, "asset_name": t1.asset_name}
```

try this :D

Comment: ts asking for two separate fields, not one compound. It's not applicable if not only JSON is used and is not looking good as for RESTful api